# How to get all metas with the record when I`m selecting by one meta

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user, the user has properties stored in a meta table. I`d to select users based on a single meta, then list them with all of their metas
Like this

```
SELECT * FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN metas m ON u.id = m.user_id 
WHERE m.key = 'eye_color' 
AND m.value = 'blue'
```

The problem is, such query won't return the other metas connected to the user.

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     metas m
     ON u.id = m.user_id 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM metas m2
              WHERE m2.user_id = m.user_id AND
                    m2.key = 'eye_color' AND
                    m2.value = 'blue'
             );
```

Comment: It is a solution for the problem, the only problem is it takes very long time to execute. Is it possible to speed up this query somehow?

Comment: @Envex . . . add an index on `metas(user_id, key, value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Slow but effective:

```
SELECT u.*,m.* FROM users u, 
LEFT JOIN metas m ON u.id = m.user_id 
WHERE u.id = (select m.user_id FROM m where m.key = 'eye_color' 
AND m.value = 'blue');
```